# Force client to change page

Tags: html, http

So I have a site where are the players are waiting in waiting room until the client that control the game press on the button to start it.

How can I force all a client to move to the "start game" page?
Right now I'm using HTTP for HTML files and I can add Javascript too (I have no idea hot wo use CSS).

Thanks

The waiting room code is somthing like this

```
<html>
    <head><title>Waiting Room</title></head>
    <body>
        please wait for the game to start
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without using Javascript. In Javascript you can then say:

```
top.location.href = "http://go.wherever";
```

Now what I got from your comments is the following situation:

You created your own http-server application serving html pages to the client.

So that means, your client currently has no logic. You should read about websockets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

What you need is more or less the following (abstracted):

Your server:

```
HTTPServer.ServeHTMLPage( htmlPage );
WSServer.WaitForIncomingSockets();
```

User's browser:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Waiting Room</title></head>
    <body>
        please wait for the game to start
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var ws = new WebSocket( someUrl );
             ws.addEventListener("message", function(e){
                 // handle incoming data
             }
             // connect to the server and keep the connection open

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When all clients are ready, send the message via the websocket to all waiting users. You will have to implement your own protocol though.

Comment: I can use Javascript.
But How can I use this in my code?'

Comment: I don't see your code, maybe you should provide some code in your question

Comment: But how do you keep the connection between the browser and the server? You either need websockets or a persistent connection to the server. You only provided some static html.

Comment: I use a socket. TCP socket.
The problem is that I close the connection after I send the page.

Comment: Ah now we get to your problem. I will update my answer

Comment: Is there a way to do it with basic HTTP, HTML and Javascript?

Comment: The only other possible solution is continuous polling where the browser asks the server each second "is there a status change?" and the server answers "no" unless all clients are ready. Never do that!